# Is there a faster way to print a set of strings into a row in excel?

Tags: vba, excel

My first pass at this involves using a keyboard shortcut to populate the selected cell and its row with "May", "Both", "Derek", [Today's date], and "Uploaded". It's currently faster than typing and I want it to be as fast as standard keyboard shortcuts; how can I clean this up?

```
Sub AutofillBothMay()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+B

    ActiveCell = "MAY"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = "BOTH"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) = "DEREK"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3) = Date
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4) = "UPLOADED"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it as,

```
activecell.resize(1, 6) = array("MAY", "BOTH", "DEREK", Date, "UPLOADED", True)
```

Don't bother with Application.ScreenUpdating.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Is there a way around printing True at the end?

Comment: @Derek he read that as an output, just remove it from the array and change the `6` to `5` in the `Resize`

Comment: @ScottCraner - Thanks for picking up on that.

Comment: Thanks, @ScottCraner. I haven't messed with anything longer than a cell function in many moons and am not yet in the swing of things.